# solve this integral, can you tell me in what order to perform the operations?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need help to solve this integral, can you tell me in what order to perform the operations? I have tried to first make the integral of each squared function, then subtract them, but I can't get to the result in the book friends, it gives $0.0000134621$

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{1}{3}sen(2x)-(0.49827+0.43539x-0.23263x^2))^2$

Comment: It sounds like you may have missed the cross terms in the overall square.  You should have things like $2 (\frac 12 \cos x)(\frac 13 \sin(2x))$.  Please show your work as we can't find the error without seeing it.

Comment: One doesn't "solve" an integral; one "evaluates" it. And, what is $sen$?

Comment: Please provide a reference for "the book" and/or the original source of the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing